# How can I drywall basement ceiling with gas and water pipelines below the joists?

Tags: drywall, joists, installation, basement-refinishing, old-pipes

I need to drywall my basement ceiling. There are gas and water pipelines below the joists as shown in the picture.

How to install drywall just below the pipes? Please help with a solution for drywall. Drop ceiling is too low and can't be raised and I don't want to raise it.

[image]

Comment: Why????  You already have a suspended ceiling, precisely because that is an easy way to have a ceiling in this situation.  What are you trying to achieve ?  One way or another you have to suspend a ceiling.

Comment: Its too too low and 25 years old. Need height to play pingpong plus need clean look.

Comment: So, raise the grid up to "just below the pipes" and buy new, clean panels in some up-to-date pattern/look if the panels are "old and dirty" - or learn for yourself through painful experience why the drop ceiling is a very good idea here.

Comment: If there are any electric junction boxes above the suspended ceiling, drywall permanently hiding them would be a violation. They have to remain accessible without tools. Something like an access panel held with screws is still no good, since a screwdriver would be needed for access.

Comment: @Ecnerwal i have lived with these panels for quite some time. Need height in basement. Just need a solution for drywall. Cant raise grid as there is AC vent (see pic) . Also i dont have skills to lift grid myself.i do have skills to work on drywall up to a level .

Comment: @MTA there is no junction . Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @MTA, I would like to see the official reference to needing to be accessible without tools such as a typical screwdriver.  By your definition, if needing to use a screwdriver for access is a violation, then probably 99% of the junction boxes, breaker panels, outlets, and light switches are in violation, since a screwdriver is needed to remove the covers for access.

Comment: Like other comments, there are lots of reasons why putting in a drywall ceiling is likely going to be a bad decision long-term.  You'll still have that HVAC ducting to worry about, and it'll be a huge pain to put up sufficient support around all that piping.  Since you mentioned a "clean" look as a desired option, I might suggest removing the suspended ceiling entirely, rent a paint sprayer, and spray the whole ceiling and piping/ducting black to give a more industrial look.   That'll give the max height, and the ceiling will feel a lot higher with it disappearing into the darkness.

Comment: @Milwrdfan The "accessible without tools" question has already been beat to death. Here's Harper's take on it: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/257083/79373

Comment: I dunno about the drywall being a bad idea comments.  A lot comes down to aesthetics and what you're happy with, and what you skill set is.  I finished off my basement with drywall as opposed to a dropped ceiling because I (and wifey) thought it looked more appropriate for a home.

Comment: I'm very confused. You want more ceiling height in your basement, but you're not willing to raise the height of the existing drop ceiling? What other sort of possible solution is there? It's really hard to tell from your pic, but commercial drop ceiling grids are suspended by wires. Get a pair of pliers and simply roll the wires up around them to shorten the wires until the grid is at the desired height. If there's some other hanging mechanism, [edit] in a better pic of that. Rolling up some wire is _far_ easier than hanging and _finishing_ drywall!

Comment: I see your unfortunate ducting: it's actually easier to move a section of grid up than it is to frame for drywall around that ducting. But you've obviously made up your mind to do it the hard way, and at that point all I can say is "Have fun with that!"

Answer (score 4):

Attach furring strips that are taller than the pipes and run perpendicular to the joists. Then attach the drywall to the furring strips.

But as others have commented, a basement with a drop tile ceiling with at least a few inches of clear space above it is worth its weight in gold when it comes time to do any kind of mechanical, electrical, or plumbing upgrade or renovation.

Comment: Is it ok to use 2x4 as furing strip ?

Comment: I would need atleast 4 inches thick furing

Comment: Drop ceiling may indeed be easier in that case. An alternative approach -- which I may need to consider since my basement does not have a lot of headroom -- is to assemble the ceiling using pieces with cut-outs so those pipes and wires continue to be exposed.

Comment: @ShivakiranNeelagiri Yes, the furring can be whatever thickness is required. With some work all of the 1.25" and smaller pipes and wires that are fixed below the floor joists could be relocated so that they cross within the thin web portion of the floor joists, eliminating much of the need for furring. The remaining places such as drain pipes and air ducts where the necessary drop-down is deeper can be framed around with wood and/or sheet metal and then drywalled.

Comment: @GregHill note the sidearm ducts blocking the web portion of the I-joists before you go too far down the path of trying to relocate the pipes and wires up there. One is visible at the very top of the picture. Even without that problem, it's easy when built and a pain to change later. With that detail it's not really possible.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It's all a question of determination! ;-) I did a poor job of alluding to re-working the water in PEX and the gas in CSST. With the flexible tubing there's almost always a way to get these to cross paths with duct work inside the joist space. Where it's truly impossible to directly cross, extra length can be added to re-route around either end of the duct.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that raising the drop ceiling in the area outside the duct is the right move here. However, if you insist on hanging drywall, you have a few options.

Suspend furring strips. You wouldn't use a full-height strip attached directly to the joist. You'd use slats mounted to the joist sides to attach to the furring strip sides. Something like this:

```
 ____ _
|____| |
  || | |
  || | |
  || | |
 _||_| |    
|____| |
     | |
   __| |
  |  | |
  |  | |
  |__|_|
```

The horizontal members must be up to the task of carrying drywall for the span between supports. Be sure to use an approved attachment method to the joists. Keep all fasteners in shear (horizontal), and use enough of adequate size for the load.

Or look for a commercial solution. There are systems similar to suspended ceiling track designed to carry drywall. You install them and screw the drywall to the channel rails.

Comment: Because getting wood furring level is going to be _so_ much easier than adjusting the drop ceiling... (Yes, this is sarcasm, the OP is obviously looking for the hardest way possible to do this job. I'm just taking one more stab at pointing that out.)